# Google Apis: API key not valid

Tags: api

```
curl 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?key=$KEY'
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.",
    "errors": [
      {
    "message": "API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.",
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "badRequest"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
    "reason": "API_KEY_INVALID",
    "domain": "googleapis.com",
    "metadata": {
      "service": "youtube.googleapis.com"
    }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

As you can see, among the various things, the error appears

**API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.**

Why?

Here is some of what you see from my configuration page (https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials) by Google Cloud
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGZuo.png

---

@StarCat you are right, I was running it from a script. here's what i get if i run the command directly from the bash terminal

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Requests from referer \u003cempty\u003e are blocked.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Requests from referer \u003cempty\u003e are blocked.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "API_KEY_HTTP_REFERRER_BLOCKED",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "consumer": "projects/480710366740",
          "service": "youtube.googleapis.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add a bit of context here. Are you running this from a script? Does the $KEY variable contain a (valid) API key?

Comment: you are right, I was running it from a script. here's what i get if i run the command directly from the bash terminal

{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Requests from referer \u003cempty\u003e are blocked.",